# Regular Expression correct Path of jpg in html

Tags: php, regex

Hello I have this kind of string:

```
<a href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/color-2.jpg"><img class="wp-image-5814 size-full aligncenter" src="hhttps://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/color-2.jpg" class="class">..
```

I want to find all phrases like it: https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/color-2.jpg using this kind of regular expression:

```
preg_match_all('("https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads.+jpg)',
```

But it returns:

```
https://ubetonowani.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/kolory-2.jpg"><img class=" wp-image-5814 size-full aligncenter" src="https://ubetonowani.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/kolory-2.jpg class=""
```

How to do that it returns on first .jpg not last?

Thanks in adnvance

Comment: Your pattern uses `.+` which will match too much, and you have to escape the dot to match it literally.  You could look at `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all` like `preg_match('~https://example\.com/wp-content/uploads\S+\.jpg~', $data, $matches);
var_dump($matches);` Also, perhaps you could use DOMDocument and get the value of the href.  Note that the second link starts with `hhttps`

Comment: Thanks, I found (https:\/\/example\.com\/wp-content\/uploads(\S+)\.jpg)perfect for me. Preg_match_all is fine beacuse I need to find all occurencess of this url in descripiton